# Is there an option to import services from other proto files?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java

Some times our grpc server went down/unhealthy so that our client unable to made a request to the grpc server, in that circumstances we are planning to write health check in generic way. We have plenty of proto buffer file let assume

a.proto

```
 syntax = "proto3"
 package com.a

 message request{
      string name = 1;
 }

 message response{
      string name = 1;
 }


 service testService{
      rpc check(request) returns (response)
 }
```

b.proto

```
 syntax = "proto3"
 package com.a

 message request1{
      string name = 1;
 }

 message response1{
      string name = 1;
 }


 service testService{
      rpc check(request1) returns (response1)
 }
```

c.proto

```
syntax = "proto3"
 package com.a

 message request2{
      string name = 1;
 }

 message response2{
      string name = 1;
 }


 service testService{
      rpc check(request2) returns (response2)
 }
```

Is there any way to write generic health checker for above three services. Below link was useful to write health check for one proto file. https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/health-checking.md

But we need to write it in generic way like create one health proto and implement those into all the grpc servers proto file. Here the problem is we can able to import **message** but not **service method.** . If you guys came across with writing health check please share your comments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I do not quite understand why you need to import health service somewhere, you must implement this service and add it to each of your servers.

Another option is to use [GRPC Services](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.grpc/grpc-services) dependency, which provides implementation of health service ([HealthServiceImpl](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/services/src/main/java/io/grpc/services/HealthServiceImpl.java)) described in [your link](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/health-checking.md).
You would create an instance of [HealthStatusManager](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/services/src/main/java/io/grpc/services/HealthStatusManager.java) which manages a health check service. Then add the service retrieved by `#getHealthService()` method to your server.

Comment: And one more idea like we can use getDefaultInstance() method to check server health